# How to share data between two app maker apps?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have created two app maker apps for different purposes. However, there are some data which is common between two apps.

How can I access/connect data between those app maker apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to setup a [Custom Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#custom) instance. Then you can point both apps at the instance in `Settings` > `Database` > `Switch to a Custom Cloud SQL Database`

**EDIT:**

The other option is setting up a calculated reference to a model in another app.

1. Grant access to App2 in App1's Google Cloud SQL Instance Authorization Settings (see above link).
2. Create a Calculated model in App2.
3. In the Datasource query:

   ```
   var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection('jdbc:google:mysql://INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/DATABASE_NAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
   var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME");
   var res = stmt.executeQuery();
   var records = [];
   while(res.next()) {
     var record = app.models.MODEL_NAME.newRecord();
     record.FIELD_1 = res.getString(1);
     record.FIELD_2 = res.getString(2);
     record.FIELD_3 = res.getString(3);
     records.push(record);
   }

   res.close();
   stmt.close();
   conn.close();

   return records;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, that will make the same database available. I am trying to use a different database for another app but access some data from the existing database.

Comment: @nexgen I updated my answer with an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for.